# Where are "Local Git Repository" path stored in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: git, visual-studio

Where are "Local Git Repository" paths stored?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio 2015 stores the list of GIT Repositories in the Registry:

Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\TeamFoundation\GitSourceControl\Repositories

Comment: that path is not present in my system

Comment: Are you looking in the registry using the REGEDIT.EXE program?

Comment: what part of the path are you missing?

Comment: Look at my path again - it is in the "14.0" folder, the screenshot you sent is of "15.0" folder

NOTE: the 14.0 folder is for VS 2015, the 15.0 folder is for VS 2017

Comment: i am using 2017, and also in 14.0, there is only "Setup"

Comment: This question specifically asked for Visual Studio 2015!!  My answer is correct for VS 2015 - sounds like you don't have VS 2015 installed so you aren't seeing the registry entries.  I've done this for VS2017 as well, but you'd need to ask a new Stack Overflow question.

Comment: at that time 2015 was latest. now 2017 is latest.

Comment: VS 2017 changed the registry hive it uses. There is now a binary file within the visual studio config folder that is a registry hive file that stores this information.

Comment: Because it's a binary file, now we can't get any useful information from that file? Any tool that can decipher that file?

Answer (score 2):

I'm working with VS2017 and after a bit of digging, I think I may have found where Visual Studio is storing the information. Go to %AppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_{instanceId}\Team Explorer\TeamExplorer.config.

That file has information like the following in it:

```
    <!--This configuration file specifies the previously-configured connection details for Team Foundation Server.-->
<server_list>
    <server url="http://mytfsserver:8080/tfs" current="yes">
        <collection guid="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx" url="http://mytfsserver:8080/tfs/defaultcollection" name="mytfsserver\DefaultCollection" current="yes" autoload="yes">
            <project projectUri="vstfs:///Classification/TeamProject/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx" name="MyTeamProject" capFlagsScc="1" supportsGit="yes" active="yes" team="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx">
                <repository type="2" name="MyGitRepo" guid="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx" activeClone="C:\Repos\MyGitRepo" isFork="False" />
            </project>
        </collection>
    </server>
```

Based on this, you can tell that MyGitRepo is stored in C:\Repos\MyGitRepo. The best way I can find to get the Visual Studio instance ID is by calling:

```
 "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe" -property instanceId
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Visual Studio likely does not have much to do with where Git is storing its metadata.  Git maintains a hidden folder called `.git` at the root level of every local repository.  In it is contained all the objects, refs, blobs, hooks, etc. which get used in Git.

Following the interface which Git exposes, if you want to see the files corresponding to a local branch you have, you can checkout that branch, or possibly checkout individual files of interest.

Comment: But when we do "Refresh" on "Team Explorer - Connect" Document window, it refreshes/ finds the git repositories by digging all the `.git` folders in the paths specified under "Local Git Repository". So, I thought it may be saving somewhere. I searched the registry, but wasn't able to get a clue.

Answer (score 1):

Well. It seems that Visual Studio 2019 has moved this information yet again. It's now in the VS private registry. Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42916299/access-visual-studio-2017s-private-registry-hive) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42779306/programmatically-finding-the-vs2017-most-recently-used-mru-solutions-and-proje), I used the following code snippet to find the local Git repositories:

```
        const string GitRepoRoot = @"TeamFoundation\GitSourceControl\Repositories";
        ExternalSettingsManager ext = ExternalSettingsManager.CreateForApplication(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe");
        SettingsStore store = ext.GetReadOnlySettingsStore(SettingsScope.UserSettings);
        var keyNames = store.GetSubCollectionNames(GitRepoRoot);
        foreach (var key in keyNames)
        {
           Console.WriteLine(store.GetString($"{GitRepoRoot}\\{key}", "Name"));
           Console.WriteLine(store.GetString($"{GitRepoRoot}\\{key}", "Path"));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Basim's answer is correct for 2019 and newer about a private registry file. I wanted to remove an old repo from the list that VS shows in the status bar. I loaded the private registry file into RegEdit, went to the folder where the repo list is stored, and removed the folder for my old repo. Then unloaded the private registry hive.

You can follow the instructions in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43012169/5149363) to load the private registry file.
I loaded it under HKLM and called it "VSHive". I'm using VS 2022 (17.0), so the repo list for me is located at: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\VSHive\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_14e0c9d2\TeamFoundation\GitSourceControl\Repositories.

Other than the VSHive name I used and the VS version (17.0_) parts, that path is where your repo list should be.

Comment: Thanks. I moved over from developer position to manager and no longer have VS installed on my new laptop. So, cannot verify. But, appreciate your answer.