# Programmatically finding the VS2017 Most Recently Used (MRU) solutions and projects

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, mru

I know that Visual Studio 2017 now supports no-registry, side-by-side installations of all SKUs (Enterprise, Professional and Community) explanations [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2016/09/15/changes-to-visual-studio-15-setup/).

We need to access the list of VS2017 Most Recently Used (MRU) solutions and projects.

For previous VS2017 version we used to query the registry for that.

- This registry-query code is still working fine when it is running from inside the VS2017 devenv process,
- but it is not working anymore when it is executed in a standalone/custom process (I mean a process that is not VS2017 devenv process) **and this is what we need to do**.

Ideally this could be done from the [VS setup API](https://github.com/microsoft/vs-setup-samples) but I cannot find any sample code.

Else we can still rely on the [RegLoadAppKey()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724886(v=vs.85).aspx) function as explained in this [VS 2017 breaking change article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/breaking-changes-2017) (any code is welcome)

Or maybe there is another API to do that?

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The recommended way to access VS 2017 settings is to use the [External Settings Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee819290.aspx):

```
ExternalSettingsManager ext = ExternalSettingsManager.CreateForApplication(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe");
SettingsStore store = ext.GetReadOnlySettingsStore(SettingsScope.UserSettings);
foreach (string name in store.GetPropertyNames(@"MRUItems\{a9c4a31f-f9cb-47a9-abc0-49ce82d0b3ac}\Items"))
{
    string value = store.GetString(@"MRUItems\{a9c4a31f-f9cb-47a9-abc0-49ce82d0b3ac}\Items", name);
    Console.WriteLine("Property name: {0}, value: {1}", name, value);
}
```

To use the External Settings Manager you need to add a reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.Settings.15.0.dll to your project.

Comment: Thanks very much Radames for this code and response.