# How to create a repository while source files are outside of solution's folder VS

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-code

I'm working on Visual Studio Code Pro 2012.

I'm trying to create a repository from an existing solution (5 projects inside) using `Microsoft Git Provider` source control plug-in. When I right click on the solution and select `Add Solution to Source Control...` I get the following warning :

[image]

Therefore only adding to the repository files located in the solution's folder but my projects source code are in other folders, how can I manage to add them into the repository (I can't put all projects in the solution's folder) ?

Answer (score -1):

Please check the following query and you might find the solution.

[Solution has projects that are located outside the solution folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56511032/solution-has-projects-that-are-located-outside-the-solution-folder/56977009)

Comment: This is not the same problem, all of his projects are within his solution folder while mine are not. And EZ-GIT plugin do not support VSC 2012.