# Pushing a solution with multiple projects to Azure Devops Repo

Tags: azure-devops, project

Hi, I'm having issues pushing multiple projects within a single solution to Azure Devops repository.

My Solution has three projects:
MyProjectAPI
MyProjectTests
MyProjectWEB

Each project lives in its own folder within a MyProjectFolder folder.

I'm trying to push all three projects to Azure Devops but only the MyProject.API is pushed.

I created a new Azure Devops repository but when i try to create and push it, i get the following message. "Your solution contains files outside the solution which will not be included...."
The Tests project and the WEB project are not pushed, only the API project

Also, i forgot to add that i have the API project and the WEB project set to multiple startup projects.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers
Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce the same with you on `Visual studio` when all projects are in different folders, but the solution is in one project(the other projects are outside in this case).

[image]

Please go to the `solution(sln) location`, check the file structure, delete the `.git`(hidden folder), navigate to the `common parent directory` that contains all your project directories, `initialize` a new Git repository instead.

[image]

Steps below:

1. Open the `Git Bash` window (from Git for Windows),go to `common parent folder` which contains all projects.Make sure only referenced projects in the common parent folder, not other non-referenced projects.
2. Type `git init` to init the new repo.
3. Type `git add .` to add all files.
4. Type `git commit -m "first commit"`
5. Go to devops repo, `delete` the existing repo which was pushed before. But create a new repository. `Don't` add readme.

[image]

6. Follow the command line below on `git bash` to `add the origin remote`.

[image]

7. Type `git push -u origin --all` to push the files(you could need to sign in).

All projects pushed to devops:

[image]

In addition, you can also check the [similar ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56511032/solution-has-projects-that-are-located-outside-the-solution-folder) which has more  detials.

Comment: Thank you very VERY much..! All three projects are now in my repository..! 
Very much appreciated.